# Why airflow task fails with try number 0 and null operator?

Tags: airflow

I have 2 airflow workers, each in a machine
In machine A a file sensor task runs, while in machine B an rsync task (copies files from A to B) and also another file sensor task for the copied files.
Sometimes rsync task fails without trying to execute and does not produce a log file.
The trigger rule of tasks is all_done and airflow v1.9

The Sensor Tasks use xcom_push and xcom_pull which I disabled but the same issue happens

```
-[ RECORD 3 ]---+-----------------------------------------------------
task_id         | task_name (rsync)
dag_id          | dag_name
execution_date  | 2019-10-08 19:30:00
start_date      |
end_date        | 2019-10-08 20:20:21.649662
duration        |
state           | failed
try_number      | 0
hostname        |
unixname        | nio
job_id          |
pool            | pool_name
queue           | queue name of machine B
priority_weight | 3
operator        |
queued_dttm     | 2019-10-08 20:20:20.550397
pid             |
max_tries       | 3
```

operator is null
retry is 0
and the state is failed

Expect that the rsync task will run.